# Check string pattern for non-unique characters

Tags: r, string, strsplit

I've a data frame with two columns: `id` and `gradelist`.

The value in `gradelist` column includes a list of grades (separated by `;`) with different length.

Here's the data:

```
id <- seq(1,7)
gradelist <- c("a;b;b",
            "c;c",
            "d;d;d;f",
            "f;f;f;f;f;f",
            "a;a;a;a",
            "f;b;b;b;b;b;b;b",
            "c;c;d;d;a;a")

df <- data.frame(id, gradelist)
df$gradelist <- as.character(df$gradelist)
```

I need to add another cloumn to chech whether all grades are the smae for each id.

The output would look like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can extract the characters and check with `n_distinct` to find the number of distinct elements is 1

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   mutate(same = map_chr(str_extract_all(gradelist, "[a-z]"), 
       ~ c("no", "yes")[1+(n_distinct(.x)==1)]))
#   id       gradelist same
#1  1           a;b;b   no
#2  2             c;c  yes
#3  3         d;d;d;f   no
#4  4     f;f;f;f;f;f  yes
#5  5         a;a;a;a  yes
#6  6 f;b;b;b;b;b;b;b   no
#7  7     c;c;d;d;a;a   no
```

Or make use of `case_when`

```
df %>% 
   mutate(same = map_chr(str_extract_all(gradelist, "[a-z]"), ~
         case_when(n_distinct(.x) == 1 ~ "yes", TRUE ~ "no")))
```

---

Or another option is `separate_rows` on the 'gradelist' to expand the data, find the `n_distinct`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    separate_rows(gradelist) %>%
    distinct %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(same = c("no", "yes")[1 + (n_distinct(gradelist) == 1)]) %>% 
    left_join(df)
```

Comment: These methods certainly work as is, but to improve readability, instead of subsetting a yes/no vector you can use `if_else` . In `map` and `summarise` the function/expression would become `if_else(n_distinct(.x)==1, "yes", "no")`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
transform(df, same = c('No', 'Yes')[grepl("^(.)\\1*$", gsub(';', '', gradelist)) + 1])
```

Output:

```
  id       gradelist same
1  1           a;b;b   No
2  2             c;c  Yes
3  3         d;d;d;f   No
4  4     f;f;f;f;f;f  Yes
5  5         a;a;a;a  Yes
6  6 f;b;b;b;b;b;b;b   No
7  7     c;c;d;d;a;a   No
```

You can also go the `strsplit` way as follows:

```
transform(df, same = c('No', 'Yes')[sapply(strsplit(gradelist, split = ';'), function(x) length(unique(unlist(x))) == 1) + 1])
```

---

*Benchmark*

We repeat the string few times. We also repeat the rows of `df` so that we end up with slightly more than 100k rows, and assign the function used by @ThomasIsCoding.

```
df$gradelist <- sapply(df$gradelist, function(x) paste(replicate(20, x), collapse = ";"))

df <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), each = 15000), ]

f <- Vectorize(function(x) ifelse(length(unique(unlist(strsplit(x,";"))))==1,"yes","no"))
```

We use `transform` for all `base` functions to emulate the behaviour of `mutate` in case of `tidy` solutions and `microbenchmark` 10 times:

```
mBench <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(

  akrun1 = { df %>% mutate(same = map_chr(str_extract_all(gradelist, "[a-z]"),
                                          ~ c("no", "yes")[1+(n_distinct(.x)==1)])) },
  akrun2 = { df %>% mutate(same = map_chr(str_extract_all(gradelist, "[a-z]"), ~
                                            case_when(n_distinct(.x) == 1 ~ "yes", TRUE ~ "no"))) },
  akrun3 = { df %>%
    separate_rows(gradelist) %>%
    distinct %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(same = c("no", "yes")[1 + (n_distinct(gradelist) == 1)]) %>% 
    left_join(df) },
  db = { transform(df, same = sapply(gradelist, function(x) { 
    nchar(gsub(paste0(substring(x, 1, 1), "|;"), "", x)) == 0}, USE.NAMES = FALSE)) },
  `M--` = { transform(df, same = factor(unlist(lapply(strsplit(gradelist, ";"), function(x) length(unique(x))))==1, labels=c("No", "Yes"))) },
  ThomasIsCoding1 = { transform(df, same = f(gradelist)) },
  ThomasIsCoding2 = { transform(df, same = sapply(regmatches(df$gradelist,gregexpr("\\w",df$gradelist)),function(x) ifelse(length(unique(x))==1,"yes","no"))) },
  arg0naut91_1 = { transform(df, same = c('No', 'Yes')[grepl("^(.)\\1*$", gsub(';', '', df$gradelist)) + 1]) },
  arg0naut91_2 = { transform(df, same = c('No', 'Yes')[sapply(strsplit(df$gradelist, split = ';'), function(x) length(unique(unlist(x))) == 1) + 1]) },

  times = 10

)
```

Results:

```
Unit: seconds
            expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
          akrun1 19.684781 19.912789 21.084244 20.646490 21.606763 24.008420    10
          akrun2 30.393006 31.066965 32.590679 31.824528 33.567449 37.780535    10
          akrun3  6.378463  7.190472  7.379439  7.373730  7.704365  8.321929    10
              db  3.738271  3.785858  3.935769  3.911479  3.926385  4.523876    10
             M--  3.551592  3.648720  3.723315  3.741075  3.798664  3.915588    10
 ThomasIsCoding1  4.453528  4.498858  4.702160  4.613088  4.823517  5.379984    10
 ThomasIsCoding2  3.368358  3.532593  3.752111  3.610664  3.773345  4.969414    10
    arg0naut91_1  1.638212  1.683986  1.699327  1.704614  1.716077  1.759059    10
    arg0naut91_2  3.665604  3.739662  3.774542  3.750144  3.774753  4.071887    10
```

Plot:

[image]

Comment: Not sure it matters in r but `df <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), each = 15000), ]` is not the best way to have a larger dataset for benchmarking purposes. If it was a for-loop in C, operating on this dataset would be much faster that doing it on an actual random dataset. Good stuff though +1

Comment: Thanks @M--, you're right indeed - didn't have time for proper sampling however from my experience I believe we would be seeing similar rankings (at least with 'native' r solutions).

Answer (score 2):

Check which character is in first place and replace all occurrences of that character with empty string. If nothing's left, that means all characters are same.

```
sapply(df$gradelist, function(x) {
    nchar(gsub(paste0(substring(x, 1, 1), "|;"), "", x)) == 0
}, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
df$same <- factor(unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$g, ";"), function(x) 
                                    length(unique(x))))==1, labels=c("No", "Yes"))

df
#>   id       gradelist same
#> 1  1           a;b;b   No
#> 2  2             c;c  Yes
#> 3  3         d;d;d;f   No
#> 4  4     f;f;f;f;f;f  Yes
#> 5  5         a;a;a;a  Yes
#> 6  6 f;b;b;b;b;b;b;b   No
#> 7  7     c;c;d;d;a;a   No
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some base R solutions.

- define your custom function `f`, i.e.,

```
f <- Vectorize(function(x) ifelse(length(unique(unlist(strsplit(x,";"))))==1,"yes","no"))
```

and then you can add column `same` by

```
df$same <- f(df$gradelist)
```

- use `regmatches` + `sapply`

```
df <- within(df,same <- sapply(regmatches(gradelist,gregexpr("\\w",gradelist)),function(x) ifelse(length(unique(x))==1,"yes","no")))
```

such that

```
> df
  id       gradelist same
1  1           a;b;b   no
2  2             c;c  yes
3  3         d;d;d;f   no
4  4     f;f;f;f;f;f  yes
5  5         a;a;a;a  yes
6  6 f;b;b;b;b;b;b;b   no
7  7     c;c;d;d;a;a   no
```

Comment: I don't.remember if it was you, but sometime back there was a question to check if the characters are same and ssomebody come up. with benchmark. `sapply(df$gradelist, function(x) length(unique(charToRaw(x))) <=2)`

Comment: @akrun it was not me.